# php regex to match operators

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I have the string

```
'OR "law studies"~2 AND here also NOT uni*  "south West" word NOT this *eng'
```

I want to use `preg_replace_callback()` to process all the process all words that are between `(AND|OR|NOT)`
I'm struggling with the regex pattern. 
Can you please suggest a regex pattern that will match that criteria 
I want the the final result to be

> OR 
>       "law studies"~2 
>   AND 
>       here also 
>   NOT 
>       uni* "south West" word 
>   NOT 
>       this *eng

OR "law studies"~2 AND here also NOT uni*  "south West" word NOT this *eng
I've tried everything with no avail

Thank you in advance

Comment: Trying to use regex to parse higher-level grammar is just doomed.  If your language is not regular, you need a parser which understands context.  Also, how do you cope if one of the quoted strings contains one of your operators as just data? `OR "this OR that" AND "this AND that"`

Comment: data inside double quotes cant have operators, they are stripped before the string is processed

Comment: The fundamental problem still holds; regex is the wrong tool for parsing higher-level syntax.

Comment: Thats what I'm slowly realizing..... sad.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can address this problem. First, I will address it using `preg_replace_callback`, since that's specifically what you are asking for in your question:

```
$string = 'OR "law studies"~2 AND here also NOT uni*  "south West" word NOT this *eng';

$string = preg_replace_callback('~(.*?)(?:OR|AND|NOT|$)~', 'callback_function', $string);

print $string;

function callback_function ($m) {

    $return_string = preg_replace('/e/', '<b><font color=red>e</font></b>', $m[1]);

    return $return_string;

}
```

This will highlight all of the "e"s in your string with bold and red.

There is also a similar function that you can use accomplish the same thing: `preg_split`.  What this does is split a string into an array, based on a regular expression.  Here's some code to demonstrate:

```
$string = 'OR "law studies"~2 AND here also NOT uni*  "south West" word NOT this *eng';

$keywords = preg_split("/(OR|AND|NOT)/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // NO EMPTY LINES
```

`$keywords` will contain the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  "law studies"~2 
    [1] =>  here also 
    [2] =>  uni*  "south West" word 
    [3] =>  this *eng
)
```

So then you can loop through each item of the array and do a replacement in the string.